# How to automate SHH commands using PuTTY

Tags: automation, putty, autoit

I am trying to automate connecting to UNIX using PuTTY and sending commands. My team use this to execute a series of processes that can get really repetitive.

I have already accomplished this using autoit v3, however I can only send commands to the putty window but not read anything from it, which doesn´t allow me to change the flow of the script based on command responses and to know exactly when a specific command executed (currently using Sleep())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Plink on this page: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

You can use Run, StdoutRead and StdinWrite to write input and read output.